# Strange behaviour of animation in viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation, viewdidappear

I am doing a simple call to a method with animation in viewDidApepar in my app, the initial position of the view that is being animated in the storyboard is (10 , 5) - almost hidden from the main view.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self doTheAnimation];    
}
```

and the method contains

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.8f delay:0.0f usingSpringWithDamping:0.5f initialSpringVelocity:1.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
     [plotView setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 40, 299, 130)];
} completion:nil];
```

**The Problem:** When the application is started - all works great with a cool "spring" effect, but when I push to another view and go back to the main view, the method with animation is called, the LOG shows that the plotView had changed frame.origin to (10,40) but it is still staying stuck at (10,5) its initial position on the storyBoard.

Comment: So you want to run the animation only once?

Comment: Try to call that method from ViewWillAppear.

Comment: @Desdenova - every time the main view is presented, so every time the viewAppears

Comment: I have tried from ViewWillAppear, sadly there is no change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self doTheAnimation];    
}
```

with

```
-(void) viewDidLayoutSubviews{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [self doTheAnimation];    
}
```

Comment: That did it quite well, I should check apples dev pages for more info about this method.

Answer (score 1):

Don't change the place of your method, just add this :

```
[plotView setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 299, 130)];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.8f delay:0.0f usingSpringWithDamping:0.5f initialSpringVelocity:1.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
    [plotView setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 40, 299, 130)];
} completion:^{
    [plotView setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 40, 299, 130)];
}];
```

Tell me if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Better is:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(doTheAnimation) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
```

Set the delay as you need.